# Linked List Front() function syntax error

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to return a Node in my Front() method of my linked list class.  The front method just returns the first element in the linked list (i.e. which is a node).  The compiler does not like this, however.  It gives me the following error.

```
Error: initial reference value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue.
```

Does anyone know a way around this??  mHead is what is underlined by intellisense.

```
Node &List::Front()
{
return mHead->getData();
}

Potion Node::getData()
{
return mData;
}
```

**list.h**

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

#include "node.h"
#include "potion.h"

class List
{

public:
//Default constructor
List();

//Copy constructor
List(const List & copy);

//Overloaded assignment operator
List &operator=(const List & rhs);

//Destructor
~List();

//Methods
void PushFront(Node * newNode);
void PushBack(Node * newNode);
void PopFront();
void PopBack();
/*const Potion &Front() const;
const Potion &Back() const;*/
Node &Front();
Node &Back();
void Purge();
bool empty();
int getNumberOfNodes();
Node * CreateNode(Potion potion);
void Save(std::ofstream & file);
void Load(std::ifstream & file);

protected:
//Data members
Node * mHead;
Node * mTail;
static int mNumberOfNodes;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `return *mHead;`? You want to return a `Node` not a `Potion`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd guess that your `getData()` function is returning a copy of the data rather than a reference. A temporary object isn't an `lvalue`.

Comment: I just changed it to return by reference and now it is saying `error: a reference of type "Node &" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value type of Potion`

Comment: @MrPickle5, your signature says you're returning `Node&` but you're trying to return a `Potion&`. You need to pick one or the other and be consistent.